# Convert Back Latitude from Hex data GREENTEL

Tags: python, gps, network-protocols

Currently I am doing a GPS Tracking project based on Django and GREENTEL
It uses this protocol
http://www.m2msolution.eu/doc/Fejlesztoi_dokumentaciok/GT03/GPRS%20Communication%20Protocol_GT03.pdf

It says how to convert Latitude/ Longitude to Hex.. but I want to convert latitude hex data to the normal form

> Conversion method: A Convert the latitude (degrees, minutes) data from
>   GPS module into a new form which represents the value only in minutes;
>   B Multiply the converted value by 30000, and then transform the result
>   to hexadecimal number. For example 22°32.7658′,（22*60+32.7658）*30000 =
>   40582974,then convert it to hexadecimal number 0x026B3F3E

how to reverse the hex to latitude conversion?

Comment: did you manage to create the listener on server port?  i am stuck.  will set bounty points for answer if you can help me. thanx!

Comment: You will have to use Twisted Matrix to create a listening server.. ;)

Comment: will check it out and will get back to you.  i managed to set up a port listener using c++ on an amazon ec2 free cloud vps server.  i am currently parsing (trying to parse) the incoming data stream.  any help will be appreciated (and rewarded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you  get the hex, convert it back to base 10 and divide it by 30000.

Get the result and divide it by 60, the integer part will be the degrees, the rest will be the minutes.

In python:

```
a = 0x026B3F3E
b = a/30000.0
degrees = b//60
minutes = b%60

print degrees, ' degrees and ', minutes, 'minutes'
>>> 22.0  degrees and  32.7658 minutes
```

Comment: I didn't get it! I have this hexa value `FD891980` (converted to decimal: 4253620608) as latitude and `04A7D3B8` (decimal: 78107576) as longitude, what is the GPS location?