# How to convert GPS Longitude and latitude from hex

Tags: gps

I am trying to convert GPS data from GPS tracking device. The company provided protocol manual, but it's not clear. Most of the data I was able to decoding from the packets I received from the device. The communication is over TCP/IP. I am having a problem decoding the hex value of the longitude and latitude. Here is an example from the manual:

Example: 22º32.7658’=(22X60+32.7658)X3000=40582974, then converted into a hexadecimal number
40582974(Decimal)= 26B3F3E(Hexadecimal)
at last the value is 0x02 0x6B 0x3F 0x3E.

I would like to know how to reverse from the hexadecimal to longitude and latitude. The device will send 26B3F3E. I want to know the process of getting 22º32.7658.

This protocol applies to GT06 and Heacent 908.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Back Latitude from Hex data GREENTEL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151896/convert-back-latitude-from-hex-data-greentel)

Comment: unbelievale which idiot invented that representation. decimal degrees * 1e6 delivers an int value, this value is then easy to encode and decode. just divide by 1e6 to get decimal degrees again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Store all four values in unsigned 32-bit variables.
   `v1 = 0x02`, `v2 = 0x6b`, `v3 = 0x3f`, `v4 = 0x3e`.
2. Compute `(v4 << 48) | (v3 << 32) | (v2 << 16) | v1` this will yield a variable holding the value 40582974 decimal.
3. Convert this to a float and divide it by 30,000.0 (your 3,000 was an error), this will give you 1,352.765
4. Chop to integer and divide by 60. This will give you the 22.
5. Multiply the number you got in step 4 by 60 and subtract it from the number you got in step 3. This will give you `1352.765 - 22*60` or 32.765.

There's your answer `22`, `32.765`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try it in my code. I will update you later. again thanks for the quick response

Comment: David, I followed your suggestion and it works. Again thanks for your help

Comment: The `vX` values are bytes, not 16-bit values, and there was an erroneous extra `|`.  The code should be `(v4 << 24) | (v3 << 16) | (v2 << 8) | v1`.

Comment: @wallyk: They're 32-bit values. Otherwise, bad things will happen when you shift them.

Comment: if this solution is not working please see this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543321/gps-tracker-received-data ...after spending time on this approach luckily I found other post and it worked for me .. hope this can help others