# GPS conversion 16digit hexadecimal value to longitude and latitude

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gps

From a device I get following type of hexadecimal value 3305511C0424573C (stored in sql database). I need to get the longitude and latitude out of it.

I also get longitude and latitude value in this format (single precision float):

- longitude = 1083419342
- latitude = 1112302388

I know the result is:

- longitude = 4.6146
- latitude = 51.09688

I tried to code several conversions in C#, but al the outcomes were not correct.

**The data from the sql server:**

StreamID  = 15620, GPS0 = 3305511C0424573C, GPS1 = 0000000000000000, GPS Longitude = 1083419342, GPS Latitude = 1112302388

label = GPS Longitude, Unit = degrees, DataItemType = Single-Precision Float, Precision = 0, BytePosition = 11
label = GPS Latitude, Unit = degrees, DataItemType = Single-Precision Float, Precision = 0, BytePosition = 12

How the data gets in the sql is an unknown for me.

**How I use the coordinates:**
`<script> var XMarker = L.marker([51.09688, 4.6146]).addTo(mymap); </script>`
This is what you need to add in your html or webapplication to get extra markers on your map that is created by leafletjs (link: leafletjs.com )

**Therefore I need to know the conversion from:**

- 3305511C0424573C  -> longitude = 4.6146, latitude = 51.09688
- 330D262A030C1247  -> longitude = 3.19325013523526, latitude = 51.222186941538

**C# answer**

```
public static double GPSCoordinateConversion(string GPSCoordinate)
    {
        double coordinate = 0;
        byte[] _byte = new byte[GPSCoordinate.Length / 2];
        double value1 = 0;
        double value2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _byte.Length; i++)
        {
            string byteValue = GPSCoordinate.Substring(i * 2, 2);
            _byte[i] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        value1 = Convert.ToDouble(_byte[2]) / 100;
        value2 = Convert.ToDouble(_byte[3]) / 10000;

        coordinate = Convert.ToDouble(_byte[0] + ((_byte[1]+value1+value2) / 60));

        return coordinate;
    }

    public static double GetLatitude(string GPSHexCoordinate)
    {
        double latitude = 0;

        latitude = GPSCoordinateConversion(GPSHexCoordinate.Substring(0, 8));

        return latitude;
    }
    public static double GetLongitude(string GPSHexCoordinate)
    {
        double longitude = 0;

        longitude = GPSCoordinateConversion(GPSHexCoordinate.Substring(8, 8));

        return longitude;
    }
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using the microsoft SQL server management studio, but I read out the sql server with an application that I made in C# (visual studio). In the application code I want to do the conversion.

Comment: Not the first time I see such data, but as far I know, there were not definitive answer on how to convert it. Could you calculate the above number from well known coordinates? This will help to find out the encoding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355604/how-to-convert-gps-longitude-and-latitude-from-hex

Comment: The longitude (4.6146) and latitude (51.09688) are the correct outcome for 3305511C0424573C. I would like the coordinates to stay in this format, I can directly input them in the leaflet.js plugin.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: I do not think it is the correct method. Also in recent question we have just decimal numbers, and a C (it seems between fields).

Comment: @RaJu: I mean: the other way. But if you can input such string in leaflet (which plugin?), could you give us the code you use to input it (so we can "reverse engineer" the source of the plugin?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi:
This is a part of the javascript that I use in my .net webapplication:
<script>
    var XMarker = L.marker([51.09688, 4.6146]).addTo(mymap);
</script>
This adds markers on a map. link to plugin: https://leafletjs.com/

outcome of sql:
StreamID GPS0                         GPS1                            longitude         latitude
15620 3305511C0424573C 0000000000000000     1083419342     1112302388

The result that I need to get as an input for the leafletjs plugin:
longitude = 4.6146
latitude = 51.09688

Comment: @RaJu: ok, I'll check. But for such additions, you should edit your question and add there the information. In any case, we are still walking around the problem. How the long coordinate was created (in database)? In past I tried with many combinations (float of any type, divisors, etc.) without luck (and with more coordinates). If we want to find more, we need to know the source of such coordinates, or putting selected coordinates and check the output. I tried again but not luck. I really need much more data

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: I have editted the question and the little bit of extra information that I have is also added. As for the source of the coorditnates, these are from the device that sends the coordinates over 3G/4G to the server. At the moment all the coordinates are almost the same, because I'm testing it in one specific place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion from 3305511C0424573C to longitude = 4.6146 and latitude = 51.09688 is as follows.

1. Split the 16 character in to two separate strings of 8 characters.
2. Split the 8 character long string in to a byte array of 4 bytes (2characters long).
3. The calculation is then as follows: `byte[0]+((Byte[1]+(byte[2]/100)+(byte[3]/10000))/60)`

Do these steps for longitude and latitude.

```
    public static double GPSCoordinateConversion(string GPSCoordinate)
    {
        double coordinate = 0;
        byte[] _byte = new byte[GPSCoordinate.Length / 2];
        double value1 = 0;
        double value2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _byte.Length; i++)
        {
            string byteValue = GPSCoordinate.Substring(i * 2, 2);
            _byte[i] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        value1 = Convert.ToDouble(_byte[2]) / 100;
        value2 = Convert.ToDouble(_byte[3]) / 10000;

        coordinate = Convert.ToDouble(_byte[0] + ((_byte[1]+value1+value2) / 60));
        return coordinate;
    }

    public static double GetLatitude(string GPSHexCoordinate)
    {
        double latitude = 0;
        latitude = GPSCoordinateConversion(GPSHexCoordinate.Substring(0, 8));
        return latitude;
    }

    public static double GetLongitude(string GPSHexCoordinate)
    {
        double longitude = 0;
        longitude = GPSCoordinateConversion(GPSHexCoordinate.Substring(8, 8));
        return longitude;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to find two different decoding.

The first part (original question), is about converting

```
longitude = 1083419342
latitude = 1112302388
```

to

```
longitude = 4.6146
latitude = 51.09688
```

The number is the integer representation of a floating point number as found on modern computer (so IEEE 754 single precision binary representation with normal integer representation. [Note: we do not have negative numbers, so we do not know how sign are represented]

The algorithm (first question)

- take each number (without the `C`, which delimit the field)
- convert it to array of bytes (4 bytes)
- read such bytes as float (float have standard format).

In C a union between `uint32_t` and `float`. In Python `struct.unpack('>f', bytearray.fromhex(hex(your_number)[2:])`. C# has BitConverter, and you see an example in [bitconverter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle?view=net-5.0). I let the other to write a correct C# answer. Note: we still need to test the negative numbers, but they should be ok (few months ago we get a similar question with Australia, so a negative latitude).

Now, then you asked about the hex number representation, and this is unrelated to the first question (so your software already do how do convert coordinates).

The problem is that I cannot get exact coordinates, but I'm very precise up 0.02 degree error. Maybe there is also a datum conversion (are your coordinates WGS84, as expected by GPS?). Or database convert the coordinates into a different datum?

In any case the solution of the second encoding:

- split the string into two half of 8 characters. The first half is latitude, and second half the longitude.
- the first group of two characters are the degree
- the second group of two characters are the primes (or minutes). So you should write the coordinates as 4'36"52.56, 3'11"35.70, 51'5"48.77, 51'13"19.87
- Then I do not know. Maybe the second group is the second, and then two decimals, or maybe 4 decimals.

Again: I do not know how negative latitude or longitude are encoded. Consider that the degrees of longitude can have 360 values, but in two characters you can encode only up to 256 values.

I do not find anymore a similar question (unanswered) few months ago, with Australian coordinates. That could help to confirm this. But you may try with many more coordinates, and check the error (and maybe to find out if there is also a datum conversion [so two different coordinates conventions]). But I think (with just 4 data) that such methods is enough precise.

Comment: I tried this as a test in a wpf application and got following outcome: latitude 6.915902E-22, longitude 0.01313115. the bitconverter code is: float value1 = BitConverter.ToSingle(byteLatitude, 0). also cutting the C out is not an option then the bitconverter complains.

Comment: I used the python version, and I get the correct result, so I think now it is the part I do not know well: C#. But I do not understand what you do. Take the number (without C), convert to number. Then extract the 4 bytes (shift and bit-and operations, or just module 256 operations, 4 times). then put these 4 bytes into the bitConverter. Ev. invert the order.

Comment: I have added my testcode and an extra coordinates example: 330D262A030C1247 -> longitude = 3.19325013523526, latitude = 51.222186941538

Comment: The error is that you split the string into 2 characters and you convert into byte. You should use this `3305511` as integer, then you find the bytes of this string (div/mod 256) [they should be exactly 4 bytes]. Then you give this in BitConverter. [You have a decimal number, not an hex number, so you cannot shortcut with 2 char at a time]

Comment: but in the second example it is very clear that the given GPS string is a hex and not an integer. Is it possible to give the python code?

Comment: Ok. right. I worked with the 1083419342, 1112302388. So now the task is to derive such numbers from the other string.

Comment: @RaJu: see the edit (and so the second decoding). That seems correct (to the minutes)